# UIScrollView in Custom UITableViewCell mixing up data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in each `UITableViewCell` of my table view that lays out `UIViews` horizontally - kind of like the "Featured" section on Apple's App Store. When I'm setting up the `UITableViewCell` I call a function within the custom `UITableViewCell` to layout the scroll view. This loops through data assigned to that tableview cell's index path and then creates the custom views and adds them to the scroll view. However, these get mixed up when scrolling the tableview and when the tableview refreshes.

If I clear the subviews before laying them out, it does work. However, I'd like to keep the scroll position at the same point every time it shows the cells. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've just added an external array that stores the current offset for each scrollview, and then manually set the offset on each scrollview everytime the tableview gets refreshed.